# Why do I have to reconnect my usb router cable?

Tags: usb, internet, networking

I have a Iball [Baton ADSD2+ Router](http://www.iballbaton.com/Product.aspx).

[image]

It's working fine but the problem is when I boot into Ubuntu I have to unplug the usb cable and then plug it again, then it starts working.

Why do I have to re connect my usb cable? Let me know if you need more details.

---

**Edit :**

I am using a direct connection. I mean to say I don't have to enter a username or password. I am connected to internet as soon as I start my router. The problem is if I start my router before my computer I have to re connect my usb cable.

**Edit 1 :**

I tried have tried to start my router after boot, but just before login and my router connects. But I don't know why my router does not connect if I start before boot ?

**Edit 2 :**

If I use Ethernet cable for connecting my router I don't have to re connect it again, but the problem still exists for the usb cable.

Thanks.

Comment: What method do you use to connect to the internet? When you're connected, right click on the network icon and select *Connection Information*, the method should be the first point on the list (*Interface*)

Comment: @ Stefano Palazzo I am using a direct connection. I mean to say I don't have to enter a username or password. I am connected to internet as soon as I start my router. The problem is if I start my router before my computer I have to re connect my usb cable.

Comment: It sounds like the usb device needs firmware or some other kind of initialisation which fails when you boot but works when the machine is booted and logged in. Can you test to see if plugging the device in before you log in but after you boot, see if it works and edit your question?

Comment: @In Protest I have tried what you said. If I start my router after boot but before login, it connects.

Answer (score 4):

This problem is not specific to your router so I dont think there is any problem with your router. In my experience, and from what I have found using Google, there is some bug in usbserial module and because of that devices using usbserial driver usually needs to be unplugged and replugged after boot so they can be correctly identified. I had this same problem with my ZTE AC2726 usb modem.

You can try manually unloading and reloading the usbserial module to see if your device gets recognized. If this doesnt work then I suggest you use ethernet i.e network cable to connect to your router instead of usb. Your router must have atleast 1 ethernet port. I am sure you wont have this problem with ethernet.

Comment: Yeah you are right I don't have this problem with Ethernet cable.